# Mathematica does't print the number 10 for small numbers on command line

Tags: output, command-line

I'm running this code from commanline using mathematica 10.1

```
#!/usr/local/bin/MathematicaScript -script

vec = Table[10.0^-v,{v,0,10,1}];
Print[vec];
```

and the output reads

```
{1., 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 1.*^-6, 1.*^-7, 1.*^-8, 1.*^-9, 1.*^-10}
```

Where did the 10 go?

Edit: A clarification.

I'm not asking about the a missing turn, namely expecting the output to be

{10. , 1. ,0.1, ...

I'm asking about the missing `10`'s in the scientific notation. I expected the output vector to be

```
{1., 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 1.*10^-6, 1.*10^-7, 1.*10^-8, 1.*10^-9, 1.*10^-10}
```

Comment: Your `v`'s are 0,1,...,10. An output of 10 would have corresponded to `v == -1`.

Comment: `1.*^-6` is *Mathematica*'s internal representation for `1.*10^-6`.

Comment: apart from writing my own code, is there away to make Mathematica printing numbers "properly"?

Comment: I presume you are using Unix.  With `wolfram.exe` version 10.4.1 running from the command prompt on Windows 10, I get what you describe as the expected output vector, but with a space used in place of an `*`.

Comment: @Yotam.  It depends what you mean by "properly".  `Format[vec,FortranForm]` might suit you, or see the other options for `Format`